# Reading multiple lines output

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

I am reading multiple lines from the command line looking like this:

```
10 12
71293781758123 72784
1 12345677654321
```

Then I calculate stuff with the data of each line and output exactly the same amount of lines.

Unfortunately, I never get more than one line output in the end, namely the result of the last one.

The input function looks like that:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = input.nextLine();
            String[] lines = line.split(" ");
            System.out.println(fct(lines[0], lines[1]));
        }
        input.close();
    }
```

fct outputs a String.

Is there something weird happening I am not aware of?

Edit: I have added fct,since this could also be the problem:

```
 public static String fct(String stringA, String stringB) {
        int [] a = new int[stringA.length()];
        int [] b = new int[stringB.length()];

        for(int i=0; i< stringA.length(); i++) {
            a[i] = stringA.charAt(i) - '0';
        }
        for(int i=0; i< stringB.length(); i++) {
            b[i] = stringB.charAt(i) - '0';
        }

        if(a.length < b.length) {
            int[] c = a.clone();
            a = b.clone();
            b = c.clone();
        }

        Stack<Integer> s = new Stack<Integer>();
        int carry = 0;
        int b_ind = b.length -1;
        for(int i=a.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
            if(b_ind >= 0) {
                int diff = a[i] - b[b_ind] - carry;
                if(diff < 0) {
                    carry = 1;
                    diff = 10 + diff;
                } else {
                    carry = 0;
                }
                s.push(diff);
            } else {
                if(carry==0) {
                    s.push(a[i]);
                } else {
                    s.push(a[i]-carry);
                    carry = 0;
                }
            }
            b_ind -= 1;
        }

        String all = "";
        while(!s.empty()) {
            all = all + s.pop();
        }

        return all.replaceFirst("^0+(?!$)", "").trim();
    }
```

The output would then be:

```
2
71293781685339
12345677654320
```

Being directly on the console on the line after the input finished.

Comment: Well, we're not aware of what fct does.  Your println prints one line per input line.  Scanner using System.in can only read and process one input line at a time.

Comment: So Scanner can be a problem here? I get a multiline input directly as the argument (I guess; its a kattis problem I am trying to solve)

Comment: I just added fct to the original problem

Comment: This works for me (as you assume), if I change the 6th line to `System.out.printf("%s %s%n", lines[0], lines[1]);`

Comment: Thats weird, that works for me as well. So it must be in fct, this seems weird to me.

Comment: As I see, `fct` substracts the smaller number from the bigger. And the output is the result.

Comment: Exactly. :) I fact, it has a mistake and does not substract correct, but thats not the cause of my question :)

Answer (score 0):

Add one line break after last input line `1 12345677654321`. Otherwise program won't read last line till you press enter(return) key.
If you want output on console like this:

```
10 12
71293781758123 72784
1 12345677654321
98
71293781685339
12345677654320
```

But you are getting this:

```
10 12
71293781758123 72784
1 1234567765432198
71293781685339
```

Notice, `98` is getting appended to last input line. And the second output is on the next line. You actually have two outputs.
And the third input has not been read by the program because third input line doesn't end in new line. If you press Enter key here the program will process the third input.

You need to make sure that there is a new line character after last input line before pasting entire input in to console.

Comment: But is adding a line break after the past line possible if I already start to output content within the while loop?

Comment: Do you want output after each input line?

Comment: I want to read everything and then, directly starting in the next line having the output of everything

Comment: To get better idea, put expected output in your opening post/question.

Comment: Done that now :)

Answer (score 0):

Just a sidenote:
I would use [java.math.BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html) in this context (math with big integers).

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.math.BigInteger;


public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (var scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
      while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        String[] lines = line.split(" ");
        System.out.println(fct(lines[0], lines[1]));
      }
    }
  }

  public static String fct(String numberA, String numberB) {
    var a = new BigInteger(numberA);
    var b = new BigInteger(numberB);

    return a.subtract(b).abs().toString();
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I know the existence of that function, but it was a personal programming exercise to try this with arrays

Comment: @hu-zza `return a.subtract(b).abs().toString();` will also work.

Comment: @onkarruikar You're right. It's overcomplicated. I changed that. :-)

Comment: @DORpapst Nice idea. :-) Maybe the source code also interesting for you. [Java 11: java.math.BigInteger](https://zza.hu/_Java_11_src/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.java)